# How to indicate empty array in HTTP request query params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

This is the way Rails accepts arrays in query parameters:

```
PUT /resource.json?sport_ids[]=133&sport_ids[]=64&sport_ids[]=71 ...
```

I tried to google this question but didn't find any explicit docs on it:

**How to tell Rails that we want sport_ids to become empty (pass empty array of sport_ids via query parameters) ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @mohameddiaa27's answer has good advice on how to achieve that by passing such data in the request body as JSON I found that I cannot rely on it within my application: I found that it is not easy to combine such passing of JSON into request body within multipart forms where I want to pass user record (with `user[sport_ids]` in it) and user's avatar image (`user[avatar]`) field.

So I continued to investigate how to achieve that using default "query parameters in a request body of POST/PUT request" approach and found the reason why I was not able to reset my sport_ids on server-side: it was the lack of permission for that specific `sport_ids` field. Now I have the following permits (pseudocode):

```
current_user.update!(user_params)

where user_params is 

user_attributes_to_permit = [
  ...
  :sport_ids,          # this is what was needed for just `user[sport_ids]` to work.
  { :sport_ids => [] } # this is needed for sport_ids non-empty arrays to work
  ...
]

params.require(:user).permit(user_attributes_to_permit)
```

so now I am able to reset the `sport_ids` array of my user by passing just `user[sport_ids]` (**without '=' and value! i.e. ...&user[sport_ids]&...**) within my query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

- HTTP requests can have only variables on the url itself. That's a limitation feature of HTTP, not Rails.
- Take a look at [How Does Rack Parse Query Params? With Parse_nested_query](http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query) to figure out how rails collects the variables into an array, it won't run out of the box in case of an empty array.

You can avoiding sending the `params["sport_ids"]` and patch your controller with:

```
params["sport_ids"] ||= []
```

---

#### The best practice to use put/post requests, is passing such data in the request body (json/xml) like:

```
  {
    "sport_ids": []
  }
```

Or with data as:

```
//...
  {
    "sport_ids": [133, 64, 71]
  }
//...
```

---

For more info about HTTP request steps, check [Running a HTTP request with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769347/running-a-http-request-with-rails/26769568#26769568).